# What's this weird character in these buttons on the mod dashboard

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools

Just spotted these.. weird (Unicode?) characters on the buttons where you can take action on the Mod dashboard

[image: Mod dashboard]

What are those characters?

(on WIndows 7 64-bit, Chrome)

Inspect element shows ellipses

```
<input title="close this question; no more answers will be accepted" class="close-question" id="close-question-336724" type="button" value="close question (4) …">
```

Comment: What do you see in the source code?

Comment: Or right click > inspect element.

Comment: That's a NUL (0x0) character or Newline.

Comment: Updated... @JoshLee

Comment: @Straitjacket seems to be ellipses

Comment: Those aren't buttons. You need to print the page out, check one of the boxes and mail or fax your official moderator decision back to the Stack Exchange offices ASAP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re ellipses. It’s kind of weird that your browser/OS can’t find the glyph when it’s using the right font for the rest of the button, but that’s Windows for you.

Comment: I read the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking correct now.

[image: mod-dashboard]

Although the code remains the same:

```
<input title="close this question; no more answers will be accepted" class="close-question" id="close-question-336724" type="button" value="close question (4) …">
```

[Diff says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/106416/revisions) the characters are same.

And there has been no updates to the browser... so *shrugs*

Comment: huh, I love mod screens :p

Comment: We didn't change anything; and if you check, it is (correctly) using `&hellip;` in the source. Basically, your machine had a sneeze, then got over it.